# How to stop rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My website has started to behave weirdly. I thought there is some problem with the rewrite url in .htaccess. So I emptied my .htaccess file. But still it is getting redirected

to http://example.com/upcoming from http://example.com/upcoming.php.

I dont understand why this url rewrite is happening.

Previously I had the following in my .htaccess file

```
     options -multiviews

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^signup$ signup.php
    RewriteRule ^twitter_signup$ twitter_signup.php
    RewriteRule ^settings$ settings.php
    RewriteRule ^log_out$ log_out.php
    RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
    RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c> 
       # Turn off mod_security filtering. 
       SecFilterEngine Off 
       # The below probably isn't needed, 
       # but better safe than sorry. 
       SecFilterScanPOST Off 
    </IfModule>
```

Due to this everytime I get 404 URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just these 2 lines in  your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
```

Also check your Apache config to see if there are any rules there.

Comment: Are you sure .htaccess is even enabled. Make sure if your `.htaccess` is enabled by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: The OP's URL may be from Google Indexes, not from Rewrite as he thinks.

Comment: Yes. It is enabled. It tested it in the same way as you mentioned and I am getting 500 error.

Comment: Run that request in Firebug and see what you get in `Net` tab. 2nd option to enable `RewriteLog` and see what it generates. I suspect `MultiViews` is still enabled in your case.